# Calling api.ai from Android

Tags: android, api, uri, dialogflow-es

I am building an android app in which I am calling api.ai. I want to parse the response and display it to users. Earlier I had written code in node.js which is as below:

```
    function sendMessageToApiAi(options,botcontext) {
        var message = options.message; // Mandatory
        var sessionId = options.sessionId || ""; // optinal
        var callback = options.callback;
        if (!(callback && typeof callback == 'function')) {
           return botcontext.sendResponse("ERROR : type of options.callback should be function and its Mandatory");
        }
        var nlpToken = options.nlpToken;

        if (!nlpToken) {
           if (!botcontext.simpledb.botleveldata.config || !botcontext.simpledb.botleveldata.config.nlpToken) {
               return botcontext.sendResponse("ERROR : token not set. Please set Api.ai Token to options.nlpToken or context.simpledb.botleveldata.config.nlpToken");
           } else {
               nlpToken = botcontext.simpledb.botleveldata.config.nlpToken;
           }
        }
        var query = '?v=20150910&query='+ encodeURIComponent(message) +'&sessionId='+context.simpledb.roomleveldata.c1+'&timezone=Asia/Calcutta&lang=en    '
        var apiurl = "https://api.api.ai/api/query"+query;
        var headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer " + nlpToken};
        botcontext.simplehttp.makeGet(apiurl, headers, function(context, event) {
           if (event.getresp) {
               callback(event.getresp);
           } else {
               callback({})
           }
        });
    }
```

My Android code is as below:

```
package com.example.pramod.apidev;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private Button listenButton;
    private TextView resultTextView;
    private EditText inputText;
    private static String API_URL = "https://api.api.ai/api/query";
    private static String API_KEY = "d05b02dfe52f4b5f969ba1257cffac37";
    private static String query;
    private static String s;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listenButton);

        resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
        inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputText);

        s = inputText.getText().toString();


        query = "?v=20150910&query=hi" +"&sessionId=1480181847573api&timezone=Asia/Calcutta&lang=en";
        listenButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {


                    URL url = new URL(API_URL + query + "&apiKey=" + API_KEY);
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);

                }


            }
        });

        }
    }
```

I need help in following:

(i) How can call the Api.ai since I am getting an error 401? Can some one tell how to exactly call Api.ai using the Node.js code?

(ii) How can parse the response and display it to users?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I'm connecting with api.ai from android app.

The steps to do are the following

**1. Add the dependencies:**

```
    compile 'ai.api:libai:1.2.2'
    compile 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.1@aar'
```

**2. Create an activity implementing AIListener.**

**3. Declare AIService,and AIDataService:**

```
    private AIService aiService;
    private AIDataService aiDataService;
```

**4. Initialize config, services and add listener:**

```
    final ai.api.android.AIConfiguration config = new       ai.api.android.AIConfiguration("API_KEY",
        ai.api.android.AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.Spanish,
        ai.api.android.AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

    // Use with text search
    aiDataService = new AIDataService(this, config);

    // Use with Voice input
    aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);

    aiService.setListener(this);
```

**5. Execute async task to make request:**

```
    AIRequest aiRequest = new AIRequest();

    aiRequest.setQuery(request);
```

//request--any string you want to send to chat bot to get there corresponding response.

```
    if(aiRequest==null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("aiRequest must be not null");
    }

    final AsyncTask<AIRequest, Integer, AIResponse> task =
        new AsyncTask<AIRequest, Integer, AIResponse>() {
                    private AIError aiError;

    @Override
    protected AIResponse doInBackground(final AIRequest... params) {
        final AIRequest request = params[0];
            try {
                final AIResponse response =    aiDataService.request(request);
                // Return response 
                return response;
            } catch (final AIServiceException e) {
                aiError = new AIError(e);
                return null;
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final AIResponse response) {
        if (response != null) {
            onResult(response);
        } else {
            onError(aiError);
        }
    }
};
task.execute(aiRequest);
```

**6. onResult method**

```
Result result = response.getResult();
```

If the result is a string, the string with the response will be in:

```
String speech = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
```

Regards.
Nuria

Comment: what is `request` in `aiRequest.setQuery(request);` and where have you defined it in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the official documentation of integrating API.AI here -

https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-android-client

Happy coding.

Comment: Please make sure your answer solves the problem without the link. You should add a short summary in case the link breaks.