# text integrating api.ai into android

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to integrate `api.ai` with android. I have followed the steps required for that. I require integrating text instead of speech. I want to receive the text as input from the user and display it. Can anyone please suggest me the solution for this?

Comment: What steps did you follow exactly? Please include the link to the relevant documentation you've read. Your question isn't very clear at the moment.

Comment: https://github.com/api-ai/api-ai-android-sdk#tutorial   .This is the procedure that I have followed.

Comment: If you tried to follow the tutorial, what *exactly* did not work for you (provide full details)? Right now, you are asking a question that is much too broad.

Comment: The above link includes integrating api.ai into android in voice format.I need integrating it in text form which means the user must be able to input his query to which he gets his query answered in textual from.Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this also answer the question??
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950190/calling-api-ai-from-android

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:Create Configuration for API AI

```
 final AIConfiguration config = new AIConfiguration("<Client access token>",
            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);
 aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
 aiService.setListener(this);

 aiDataService = new AIDataService(config);
 aiRequest = new AIRequest();
```

Step 2:Set your text here

```
 aiRequest.setQuery(message);
```

Step 3:Get your response from API AI using AsyncTask

```
new AsyncTask<AIRequest,Void,AIResponse>(){

                    @Override
                    protected AIResponse doInBackground(AIRequest... aiRequests) {
                        final AIRequest request = aiRequests[0];
                        try {
                            final AIResponse response = aiDataService.request(aiRequest);
                            return response;
                        } catch (AIServiceException e) {
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(AIResponse response) {
                        if (response != null) {

                            Result result = response.getResult();
                            String reply = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
                            sendMessage(message);
                            mimicOtherMessage(reply);

                            mListView.setSelection(mAdapter.getCount() - 1);

                        }
                    }
                }.execute(aiRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right -- you do not need the Voice input for your Android application and simply want the user to type in the text in their Android application. Post that, you are expecting to pass on that request to API.AI for further processing and a possible response.

If the above is correct, then you do not need any of the Voice capability Activities. Simply take it in the text from the User and pass that on to the API.AI HTTP API.